# Valores em Gráficos

Tags: chartjs

Como faço para que apareça valores ao lado das barras no gráfico?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
var ctx = document.getElementById('desafios').getContext('2d');
   window.myHorizontalBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: grafDesafios,
    options: {
     // Elements options apply to all of the options unless overridden in a dataset
     // In this case, we are setting the border of each horizontal bar to be 2px wide
  
                                        elements: {
      rectangle: {
       borderWidth: 2
      }
     },
     responsive: true,
     legend: {
                                             display: true
     },
     title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Desafios'
     },
                                        scales: {
                                            xAxes: [{
                                                ticks: {
                                                    suggestedMin: 0,
                                                    suggestedMax: 200000,
                                                    stepSize: 25000,
                                                    fontSize: 10
                                                }
                                            }],
                                            yAxes: [{
                                            ticks: {
                                                fontSize: 8
                                            }
                                        }]
                                        },
                                        animation: {
                                            animateRotate: true,
                                            animateScale: false,
                                            duration: 3000
                                        },
                           }
   });
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Sua pergunta está um pouco mal formulada, você precisa que esse texto apareça no final das barras a direita é isso mesmo ? Ou você quer um gráfico como o da primeira imagem com o texto a esquerda ? E de qualquer forma esse fragmento de código não ajuda muito, poderia postar o código completo com o HTML e outros elementos inclusos para que possamos o auxiliar de forma mais fácil por favor ?

Comment: Sim na verdade eu preciso que o valor apareça ao lado das barras (ao final das barras) ,  por exemplo a quarta barra (de cima para baixo) deve aparecer ao lado 100.000.

Comment: O que você quer exatamente então é que os dados que estão aparecendo no eixo X do gráfico passem a ser exibidos no final da barra certo ? Se sim você deseja que os valores do eixo x deixem de ser apresentados ou quer duplicar os 2 ?

Comment: Sim ... eu quero q o valor exato de cada barra apareça.. por exemplo na segunda barra de cima para baixo que apareça o valor correspondente a ela,  ou seja algo entre 100.000 e 125.000.  O que está embaixo no eixo X fica como esta.